# Create an Inbox List in Trello for recurring task cards to automatically appear when due

Tags: trello

I'd like to see a built-in Inbox list where recurring task cards appear on que. Eventually forwarding email from whatever email client you like to a trello address can send a card to the Inbox.

Moving the task cards to categories and active lists for prioritization is easy from there.

A template for a standard set of GTD lists would be nice too.

Inbox, Work, Home, School, Todo Today, Todo Tonight, Done

Comment: This is really more of a feature request than a question

Comment: -1 this isn't a question in its present form.  You may want to edit your question in a way that makes it answerable.  You seem to have known that these features didn't exist when you asked the question.

Comment: Please send feature requests directly to Trello at support@trello.com

Answer (score 0):

This sort of feature doesn't exist, but creating cards via email is a [proposed feature](https://trello.com/card/board/create-cards-via-email/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4dbb1b876cc6af2018088eb0)